# How to extend "Some people do this, other people do that..." by a third part?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

To describe differences in the behaviour of people often the expression *"Some people do ..., other people do ..."* is used. For example: *"Some people drive cars, other people ride bicycles"*.

If I wanted to extend this expression by a third group of people/behaviour, what would be the idiomatic extension? Like

> Some people drive cars, other people ride bicycles, **even(?) other** people go by the tube.

Comment: I think it would go like *Some ..., some ..., and some*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is

... (while) (yet) others ...

> Some people sight-see in their cars, some ride bikes, while others
>   prefer to walk.
>
> Some people sight-see in their cars, some ride bikes, yet others
>   prefer to walk.
>
> Some people sight-see in their cars, some ride bikes, while yet others
>   prefer to walk.

I have listed them here in what I feel to be an order of increasing contrast.

Comment: "Still others" is also frequently used.